# Как проверить есть ли директория в директории?

Tags: java, android

Юзер создает директорию с именем, мне нужно сделать так, что если директория в которой он создает новую директорию уже содержит такое имя, то функция возвращает `true` и наоборот если такой директории еще нет...

Я так понимаю, что нужно прочитать все названия директорий в массив и потом сравнивать с названием которое хочет создать юзер, но как прочитать все названия в массив?

Я начал писать функцию, но не могу догадаться как прочитать названия

```
private boolean isContains(String str) {
    boolean result = false;
    String path = UtilClass.getAvatarPath(context).toString();
    File file = new File(path);
    return result;
}
```

Подскажите как это сделать ?

Comment: Там (File класс) есть что-то типа listFiles, возвратит список всех файлов. А у списка есть метод contains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В итоге я для себя сформировал такой метод, который проверяет содержиться ли папка по указаному адресу или нет

```
public static boolean isNameFree(Context context, String name) {
    final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() +
            "/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic/files" +
            "/" + getEmail(context) + "/AvatarPackage/" + name;

    File file = new File(path);
    return !file.exists();
}
```

Comment: Снова вас побеспокою. Мне кажется, что в конце надо добавить ! перед file. А в остальном, вроде все в порядке, так как полный путь совпасть не может.

Comment: @iramm Если исходить из того, что метод проверяет свободно ли имя для папки, судя по названию, то вы правы.

Comment: @iramm Спасибо) Добавил в ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то

```
file.exists()
```

Вам прекрасно должен подойти. Если `true`- то такая дериктория есть, если `false` то нет

Comment: Да, все верно... как то я все усложнил. Спасибо

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko  Из доков: "file.exists() ... Returns a boolean indicating whether this file can be found on the underlying file system."  То есть речь идет не о конкретной папке, а о файловой системе. И кроме того, не проверяется, является ли совпадающее по имени значение файлом или папкой. То есть возможны баги в будущем. Что скажете?

Comment: @iramm не совсем понял, почему возможны баги? В моей апп так устроено, есть папка для  папок картинок конкретного аватара. То есть если создается новый аватар, то для всех его картинок создатся папка в папке для картинок и туда отправятся на сохранение все эти файлы. Единственное что мне нужно было это проверить когда юзер создает новую папку для картинок аватара, содержится ли уже папка с таким именем или нет... А вы что имели ввиду?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Мне сложно въехать в специфику вашей задачи. Я имела в виду, что раз речь идет о файловой системе (правда, что значит underlying?), то если где-то еще (не в вашей папке) уже есть  папка с названием, которое вы ищете, то указанный метод вернет true, хотя в интересующей вас папке такая директория еще не создана. Одна надежда на underlying file system. Возможно под этим термином имеются в виду текущая папка и вложенные в нее. Тогда опасность меньше или с учетом вашей специфики, может, ее и вовсе нет.))

Comment: @iramm опубликовал свой ответ. В моем случае я не проверяю название по всей файловой системе, только в конкретной директории